# Adjust .NET Linq results list so it shows ASC future then DESC past list which can be skipped for a single page

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've read the many related questions but can't find this exactly.

I'm trying to adjust the ordering on an OLD .NET (4.0) web page so it shows events that are upcoming ASC (showing closest in the future first), followed by events in the past showing them DESC in a single list that is skipped to take a 'page' of results.

So like this:

- Event 1 - tomorrow
- Event 2 - in a week
- Event 3 - in a month
- Event 4 - yesterday
- Event 5 - a week ago
- Event 6 - a month ago

The current function grabs the list and does a sort, skip and take (a single page):

```cs
// Currently this creates a single list order by date desc
var numToLoad = 20;
var list = _context.AllItems.Where(i => i.typeTitle == source);
var items = list.OrderByDescending(i => i.dateCreated).Skip((pageNum - 1) * numToLoad).Take(numToLoad);
```

I have tried making two lists, ordering each appropriately, and then concatenating them, but then I can't do a skip, as that requires a sorted list.

```cs
// We need a single list but with upcoming dates first, ascending, then past dates descending
var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
var listFuture = _context.AllItems.Where(i => i.typeTitle == source && i.dateCreated >= dateNow).OrderBy(i => i.dateCreated);
var listPast = _context.AllItems.Where(i => i.typeTitle == source && i.dateCreated < dateNow).OrderByDescending(i => i.dateCreated);
var listAll = listFuture.Concat(listPast);
var itemsAll = listAll.Skip((pageNum - 1) * numToLoad).Take(numToLoad); // <-- this gives an error as it's not sorted
```

So I don't have to rewrite all the code that handles the returned list (pagination etc) I'd really like to be able to return a single list from the function!

I did see that it might be possible to do conditional sorting, then do the skip and take in a single linq but I just can't get anything like that to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using EF or other ORM? How does list item look like? Can you just sort `listAll`?

Comment: Entity. The listAll is ordered as it needs to be - future ASC then past DESC, if I order the whole list then I lose that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that .Concat() of two queries loose ordering when translated to SQL (you cannot to UNION two queries with different order each).

If you are using MSSQL, you can use ordering like that:

```
var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
var query = _context.AllItems
  .Where(i => i.typeTitle == source)
  // future items first
  .OrderBy(i => i.dateCreated >= dateNow ? 0 : 1)
  // items which closer to now first
  .ThenBy(i => Math.Abs(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", dateNow, i.dateCreated).Value));

var list = query.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: Great thanks, let me try this and come back to you :)

Comment: Sigh. The old website uses EntityFramework.ru, v 5.0. And so the System.Data.Entity.SqlServer ref doesn't work. Is there an older way to make that date diff that doesn't rely on a modern entity version?!

Comment: In EF 5.0 these functions are in different namespace - System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions